# APEX Application does not show on All Application page

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

It might be foolish for some, but its irritating for others.

I have imported an existing application into `APEX` with a new application ID, but the application does not show up in `Application Builder->All Application` page.

To access the application, we have to open the old application and change the application ID in url.

Any idea how to display the application Icon on `Application Builder->All Application` page.

Comment: Can you reproduce this bug? Try to define, is it a bug of application or bug of your apex workspace. For example, import a new application to to your workspace and export this broken application to another workspace (to apex.oracle.com, for example)?

Comment: May be it is Shadow Application? When you creating translation (read Developer Guide), there is copy of your application created, its called Shadow Application and d not shown in application list.

Comment: I'm not sure about apex 5 but, up until 4.2 you couldn't change the application number once created, no even importing it.

Comment: Could it be on page 2?